# Is there a good sourcebook for practice exercises?

Tags: learning

I'm looking for a book full of practice exercises. I find that, while my vocabulary is getting better and my knowledge of grammar improving, it would really help to do more exercises and compare my understand to reality. The only thing I can find is this? Is there anything else?

[http://www.amazon.com/Basic-German-Grammar-Workbook-Workbooks/dp/0415284058](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0415284058)

Comment: not sure if this might be something you are looking for, but you might want to check this out: http://www.mein-deutschbuch.de/lernen.php

Comment: What level are you at? For A2/B1 I found this http://www.amazon.de/%C3%9Cbungsgrammatik-f%C3%BCr-die-Grundstufe-L%C3%B6sungsheft/dp/3922989713/ref=sr_1_86?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1367323849&sr=1-86&keywords=Deutsch%3B+Grammatik book very good, and for B2/C1 the same publishers have http://www.amazon.de/%C3%9Cbungsgrammatik-f%C3%BCr-die-Mittelstufe-Mittelstufe/dp/3922989519/ref=pd_sim_b_1 (you need to buy the solution books separately)

Answer (score 3):

Try [Grimm Grammar](http://coerll.utexas.edu/gg/)

This is an excellent ressource for german grammar and suitable for nearly every level of knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good resource, around 30 exercises that are like games to test yourself at [www.germanexercises.eu](https://www.germanexercises.eu)

I've done all of them :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23559)

Comment: Well. The question was about practicing German, and the link is to the page that lists the exercises. Isn't it the answer to the question asked. I tried some of them and those have sentences that German speakers use in everyday life. ?